# SQL Database with user defined columns for different entries

Tags: database, database-design

I want a data base in addition to having entries to the base fields a user can add fields and it's values for particular entry.

A way I was thinking that with base fields I will have a remarks field in which I will save a JSON to save extra fields.

Please provide some suggestion because I am bit skeptic about the retrival of JSON and also efficient search on the basis of some user defined fields.

Comment: This is so vague that I doubt anyone can give any suggestions to this. Is this even about relational databases? NoSQL? Something else?

Comment: There are lots of options, personally I'm inclined to create a UserValues table, and record ValueTitle and UserValue columns, or possibly include a ValueType and separate TextValue, IntValue etc columns. Its going to make searching simpler. Do you also want to allow for a standard set of new values, or is it completely up to the user, including spelling mistakes, for new user fields?